# PHP Array, if duplicate id concat values and delete duplicate

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
array(2) {
["sys_ID"]=> string(32) "ab0ce921dba8a810f6db3892399619d9" ["sites"]=> array(5) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        ["sys_ID"]=> string(32) "448ce5a1dba8a810f6db3892399619ba" ["service"]=> string(4) "IDMB" } [1]=> array(2) {
        ["sys_ID"]=> string(32) "448ce5a1dba8a810f6db3892399619ba" ["service"]=> string(4) "ODMB" } [2]=> array(2) {
        ["sys_ID"]=> string(32) "598ce5a1dba8a810f6db3892399619bc" ["service"]=> string(4) "IDMB" } [3]=> array(2) {
        ["sys_ID"]=> string(32) "876ce5a1dba8a810f6db38923996199f" ["service"]=> string(4) "IDMB" } [4]=> array(2) {
        ["sys_ID"]=> string(32) "876ce5a1dba8a810f6db38923996199f" ["service"]=> string(4) "ODMB" } } }
```

If there is a duplicate `['sys_ID']` I want to change the first `['service'] => "IDMB,ODMB"` then delete the duplicate value so there is only 1. So the above would become

```
    array(2) {
["sys_ID"]=> string(32) "ab0ce921dba8a810f6db3892399619d9" ["sites"]=> array(5) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        ["sys_ID"]=> string(32) "448ce5a1dba8a810f6db3892399619ba" ["service"]=> string(4) "IDMB,ODMB" } [1]=> array(2) {
        ["sys_ID"]=> string(32) "598ce5a1dba8a810f6db3892399619bc" ["service"]=> string(4) "IDMB" } [2]=> array(2) {
        ["sys_ID"]=> string(32) "876ce5a1dba8a810f6db38923996199f" ["service"]=> string(4) "IDMB,ODMB" } ]} }
```

The first array was made getting POST values;

```
<?php    
foreach ($_POST['services'] as $item) {
            $parts = explode(',', $item);
            $siteID = $parts[1];
            $services = $parts[0];
            $data['sites'][] = [
                    'sys_ID'  => $siteID,
                    'service' => $services
            ];
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the way you generate your array to something like this:

```
<?php
$data = [
    'sites' => [],
];
foreach ($_POST['services'] as $item) {
    // Gather your data
    $parts = explode(',', $item);
    $siteID = $parts[1];
    $services = $parts[0];
    
    // Set flag to remember whether you need to add it
    $add = true;
    
    // Loop through existing data and check if the sys_ID already exists
    foreach ($data['sites'] as &$dataDetails) {
        
        // It does ... so just append your service
        if ($dataDetails['sys_ID'] === $siteID) {
            $add = false;
            $dataDetails['service'] .= ',' . $services;
            break;
        }
        
    }
    
    // Couldn't find the sys_ID => Add new entry
    if ($add) {
        $data['sites'][] = [
            'sys_ID'  => $siteID,
            'service' => $services
        ];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Side note: this is not very efficient. But if your post data is small, then this shouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to fill the array properly from the beginning; however I will still post a solution. We have the array defined like this:

```
$arr = array(
    'sys_ID' => 'ab0ce921dba8a810f6db3892399619d9',
    'sites' => array(
        0 => array(
            'sys_ID' => "448ce5a1dba8a810f6db3892399619ba",
            'service'=> "IDMB" 
        ),
        1 => array(
            'sys_ID' => "448ce5a1dba8a810f6db3892399619ba",
            'service'=> "ODMB" 
        ),
        2 => array(
            'sys_ID'=> "598ce5a1dba8a810f6db3892399619bc", 
            'service'=> "IDMB" 
        ),
        3 => array(
            'sys_ID'=> "876ce5a1dba8a810f6db38923996199f", 
            'service'=> "IDMB" 
        ),
        4 => array(
            'sys_ID'=> "876ce5a1dba8a810f6db38923996199f", 
            'service'=> "ODMB" 
        )
    )           
);
```

To merge the elements like described, you can do the following loop:

```
// For each site (1)...
for($i=0; $i<count($arr["sites"])-1; $i++){
    // Take each of sites starting from the next one to the end (2)
    for($j=$i+1; $j<count($arr["sites"]); $j++){
        // If there is a match in sys_ID beteen (1) and (2)
        if($arr["sites"][$i]['sys_ID'] == $arr["sites"][$j]['sys_ID']){
            // Merge the service into (1) with comma separation
            $arr["sites"][$i]['service'] = $arr["sites"][$i]['service'].",".$arr["sites"][$j]['service'];
            // then delete (2)
            array_splice($arr["sites"],$j,1);
            $j--;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this will reindex the numebers (1,2,3...). If you wish to preserve them, you can use unset() instead.